# will + be + verb ing meaning

Tags: verbs, future-continuous

I see one of my friends posted this status:

"Halloween celebration @ MBC - One of the last shots I'll be taking here"

Anyone could explain why she uses "I'll be taking" but not "I will take"? any difference between these two uses

Comment: It's the same as the difference between *I'll leave soon* and *I'll be leaving soon*, which is to say "not much". Arguably in *some* contexts the continuous form slightly emphasises the "extended" nature of the "future action", but in your specific context it really doesn't amount to a meaningful nuance. Not all alternative phrasings carry alternative meanings.

Comment: @Fumblefingers I was wondering- does the future progressive work with verbs that convey a very brief action too? For instance drop, shoot, kick etc ////// ex: I'll be dropping it off at the post office later today/ I'll be drooping by his place later

Comment: @Daniel: using a "progressive" form often (not sure about *always*) implies that the *duration* of the (possibly future) action/activity is contextually relevant. For example, *I'll be walking the dogs this afternoon, so I might not be in when you arrive.* As compared to *I'll walk the dogs this afternoon, so they won't keep pestering you to take them out,* where it's the fact of the action being *completed* that matters, not the duration. Note that contexts such as *I'll be cooking roast chicken on Sunday [if you'd like to come to dinner]*, imply "continuity" between present and future.

Comment: *Settle down to sleep now kids. I'll be turning off the light in a few minutes* implies a strong link between time of speaking and impending "lights out" (arguably, emphasising *current* requirement to prepare for that). Simple future *...I'll turn off the light in a few minutes* is just a straightforward statement on a par with *I'll see you all bright and early in the morning*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Will + be + verb -ing)" vs "Will + verb" ?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142165/will-be-verb-ing-vs-will-verb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Will be [verb]-ing is future continuous tense.  It is used to describe a future, action that will occur over some period of time:

> All day tomorrow I **will be studying** for the big exam.

As you know, it's often grammatical to substitute the simple future for the continuous, without changing the meaning:

> All day tomorrow I **will study** for the big exam.

There is a *slight* difference in nuance, though.  Any continuous tense describes *ongoing* action, as if you *are watching* it happen.  For example:

> Tomorrow the Packers **will be facing** the Patriots to determine who goes to the championship.

In the above sentence there is little difference between "will be facing" and "will face", but if a sports announcer were to say this sentence, the *feeling* is that we could be watching the game as it happens.  There's a kind of *dramatic immediacy* when we use the future continuous.

(BTW the verb "to face" or "to face off", in sports, means "to compete against, face-to-face".  See [verb definition 3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face))

In the same way, your friend says "I'll be taking shots" because she expects you to *be there*, and possibly *join her* in taking the shots.  She could have said "I will take" but that is more matter-of-fact, and doesn't include the suggestion of *personal invitation*.